# RethinkDB: Can I group by day / week / month?

Tags: rethinkdb

My table has a `timestamp` field, which is a standard RethinkDB date field.
Can I group rows by day / week / month using this timestamp field? Couldn't find any examples in the group() docs.

Answer (score 7):

To group by month, day, or day of week individually:

```
r.table(...).group(r.row('timestamp').month())
r.table(...).group(r.row('timestamp').day())
r.table(...).group(r.row('timestamp').dayOfWeek())
```

Grouping by the week isn't as easy at the moment, because ReQL is currently missing a function to get the week number from a data (see https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2055 ). You can probably work around that by using some custom JavaScript code through `r.js()`. Please let me know if this is important for you, so I can look into it.

If you want to group by combinations of multiple things, e.g. day and month:

```
r.table(...).group([r.row('timestamp').month(), r.row('timestamp').day()])
```